# VirtualHost still active after removing from component

Tags: restlet

When I remove a previously added VirtualHost from the hosts list of a running component, then the virtual host still keeps being used.

```
    Component component = new Component();
    component.getServers().add(Protocol.HTTP, 8080);
    component.getDefaultHost().attachDefault(DefaultResource.class);

    VirtualHost host = new VirtualHost(new Context());
    host.setHostDomain("myhost\\.org");
    host.attachDefault(MyHostResource.class);
    component.getHosts().add(host);
    component.start();
    Thread.currentThread().sleep(5000);
    System.out.println("Stopping myhost");
    component.getHosts().remove(host);
```

After 5 seconds a GET query to http://myhost.org should give the output of DefaultResource, but it keeps giving the output of MyHostResource, but only after submitting a GET during the first 5 seconds. It seems that some routing information is keept in a cache.

I am currently building an OSGi application with dynamic insertion/removal of VirtualHosts. But if the virtual host is not correctly disconnected I get ServiceUnavailableExeptions as a result.

How should I remove the virtual host and update the routing caches correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found it. Calling

```
 component.updateHosts()
```

did the trick.